# Showing that $Tx(n)=nx(n)$ in inner-product space $l^{2}$ satisfies $(Tx,y)=(y,Tx) \ \forall x,y \in A$ yet T is unbounded

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products, unbounded-operators

Define A as: $ A\equiv \left \{ x\in l^{2}:\sum_{1}^{\infty}n^{2}{\left |x\left (n\right )\right |}^{2}<{\infty} \right \} $
Define a linear operator $T: A\rightarrow l^{2}$ (where $l^{2}$ is sequence space) by: $Tx(n)=nx(n)$ for $x\in A $ and $n=1,2,...$
I am trying to show that T satisfies the (inner product) condition: $(Tx,y)=(y,Tx) 
\ \forall x,y \in A$ yet T is unbounded.

To show it is unbounded, I used the unit basis vector $e_{n}$ to suggest:
$\left \|Te_{n}  \right \|=\left \|ne_{n}  \right \|=n\left \|e_{n}  \right \|$ therefore it is unbounded. Is this a valid approach? 
Secondly I am unsure how to show $(Tx,y)=(y,Tx)$ as I essentially have $\sum_{1}^{\infty}nx(n)\bar{y(n)}=\sum_{1}^{\infty}y(n)\bar{nx(n)}$ and I am unsure how to prove equality--any helpful hints?

Comment: Use the polarization identity.

Comment: Do you mean to use polarization identity to show (Tx,y)=(y,Tx) in general, not specifically for T above? I have done that initially, but I was not able to reconcile that with the fact that when I compute the IP with T, the two sides equal only in the case of Real numbers (this was also pointed out in the answer by Berci below). Do you know how to reconcile the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you wanted to write $(Tx, y) =(y, Tx)$, as the other one, $(Tx, y) =(y, Tx)$ would only mean that $(Tx,y)$ is *real*, which is obviously true for arbitrary $T$ if you work over $\Bbb R$, but is false over $\Bbb C$.

Your argument for unboundedness is correct.

To show the self-adjoint property:
$$(Tx, y) =\sum_n\overline{n x_n}y_n=\sum_n n\bar x_ny_n=(x, Ty)\,. $$